# performance test on 1000 messages in rabbitmq queue using Gatling

Tags: rabbitmq, gatling, scala-gatling

I have 2 rabbitmq queues, one is message queue and other is result queue. I want to test the performance of message queue
When i send list of json to message queue one by one, this message is processed and then i get response in result queue in this format

for one message 5 response messages

```
{id:1234,status:processing}
{id:1234,status:processing}
{id:1234,status:processing}
{id:1234,status:processing}
{id:1234,status:complete}
```

Now I want to check the complete status and find the time required to get a response with complete status

this is  the scenario

```
val scn: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("test1")
.exec {
  s: Session =>
    val list = data.toList *// data is the list of messages(they can me from 100 to 1000 or more)*
    s.set("list", list)
}
.foreach(s=>s("list").as[Seq[String]],"message") {

  exec(
    amqp("publish message to exchange").requestReply
      .queueExchange("message")
      .replyExchange("result")
      .textMessage("${message}")
      .priority(0)
      .contentType("application/json")
      .headers("test" -> "performance")
      .check(
        jsonPath("$.id").exists,
        jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("co-id"),
        jsonPath("$.status").is("Complete"),  *//this one fails with error msg- found processing*
        jsonPath("$.status").saveAs("status")
      )
  ).pause(20)
    .exec({session =>
    val status = session("status").as[String]
      val coId = session("co-id").as[String]
    println("Response body:::",coId,status)
    session
  }).pause(5)

}.pause(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/gatling-amqp-plugin/blob/master/src/test/scala/ru/tinkoff/gatling/amqp/examples/RequestReplyWithOwnMatchingExample.scala . There you will find an example how to write a test with your own matching method.

If I understand your question correct you could return from the method "matchByMessage"

- for sending methods something like "messageId+"_"+complete"
- for receiving message you have to extract the state from the message

If you don't want to run the plugin in debug-mode locally you you could print the message parameter from the method.